# How do you french trim a lamb shank?

Tags: lamb, butchering

I could only find a couple of written tutorials and they weren't very good.  Can anyone explain it to me or provide a good tutorial?

Comment: Top video result on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD0UCd-IeZY

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_5822445_french-trim-lamb-shanks.html) clearly explained the chef style frenching.